# Making a dialog box that times out in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, timeout

Imagine that I have an operation that might succeed or might fail, and which I could retry *ad nauseam* (in this case, getting a lock on some file). I'd like to retry the operation repeatedly, but give the user an option to indicate he'd like to give up.

Consider this code:

```
import easygui

def get_lock():
    # ...imagine something meaningful happens here, but fails...
    return None

while True:
    lock = get_lock()
    if lock:
        break

    answer = easygui.ynbox("Do you want to keep trying?")
    # Would like to just assume the answer is "yes" if the user doesn't click no within 30s    

    if 0 == answer:
        break
```

This code doesn't quite work for me because easygui.ynbox doesn't support a timeout. How can I get the timeout, ideally while hiding a lot of the complexity of doing so?

Comment: It sounds like you want a "timeout" set by the number of tries, not by actual time, right?

Comment: No, what I want to do is automatically try again unless the user clicks a button telling the program to stop. So when the timeout expires I don't give up--I actually try again to grab the lock.

Comment: You're either going to have to modify the `easygui` module to do this or create your own `Tkinter` (or `tkinter`) [dialog window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm). You can use the code in the `easygui.buttonbox()` function as a template.

Comment: To do the timeout itself, you can use either the `after()` or `after_idle()` [_Universal widget methods_](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) to call a function which cancels the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [@martineau's pointer](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) it turned out to be pretty easy to get this. You just need to add

```
boxRoot.after(timeout_ms, boxRoot.quit)
```

right before

```
boxRoot.mainloop()
```

in `easygui.buttonbox`.